# How can I draw a regression based on two specific range of points in Excel?

Tags: excel, statistics, linear-regression

I want to draw a regression line in Excel based on two specific range of points in Excel? For example, I have the following data:

```
Mydata
5
7
9
8
9
10
13
```

A linear regression line in Excel would produce the following.

[image]

Instead, I want to produce a linear regression line starting from the third data point (9) to the last data point (13) while showing all data points in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper column which has only the values of interest. Plot both lines as line chart with chart style that includes markers. Then remove the lines.  Add a regression line to the second series which has the smaller number of values. Format the dots to look like each other. Remove the first line legend entry.

Example (right is final):

[image: Example]

To show the trend line differences:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: If it might be of use, an equation that fits all of the data points smoothly is "Y = a * X * X * (1.0 + b * exp(c * X))" with coefficients a =  2.4452083833190272E-01, b =  4.3698021678408793E+01, c = -9.1870996507074199E-01

Comment: @JamesPhillips  Sounds good but I am not really sure why they want to do this anyway? Do you?

Comment: I wrote "If it might be of use" for that very reason.

Comment: Please don’t get me wrong. I am grateful. I am not sure how to incorporate that into my answer. :-)

Comment: Would I simply say have another series instead of the helper which fits that equation line?

Comment: This is a different equation, curved to fit the shape of the data and not a straight line.